# Why does this throw a JSON parsing error and why can't I trap it?

Tags: sql-server, json

Consider the below function which returns a portion of a well-formatted JSON object. It will return "Bad JSON" when the JSON is not well-formatted. Importantly, it will not error when the JSON is not well-formatted.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TestJSONParse
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        v3 = isNull(t2.v2,t1.v1)
    FROM        (
                    SELECT
                        v1 = 'Bad JSON'
                ) AS t1
    LEFT JOIN   (
                    SELECT
                        v2 = JSON_VALUE(@nv,'$.prop')
                    WHERE ISJSON(@nv) <> 0
                ) AS t2
    ON          1 = 1
);
GO

SELECT * FROM TestJSONParse('{"prop": "Good JSON"}');
SELECT * FROM TestJSONParse('zzzz');
GO
```

Results:

```
v3
Good JSON

v3
Bad JSON
```

So far, so good.

Now I want to use this function in a procedure and feed it the same bad JSON:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestJSONParseProc
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);
        SELECT
            @v = v3
        FROM        TestJSONParse(@nv);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            Result = N'I have caught an error.';
    END CATCH
END
GO

EXEC TestJSONParseProc
    @nv = N'zzzz';
GO
```

Results:

```
Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Procedure TestJSONParseProc, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 45]
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'z' is found at position 0.
```

1. Why does this error occur? The evaluation of JSON_VALUE should not take place because ISJSON should be 0 and therefore the row is filtered from the results.
2. Why isn't this error caught by the BEGIN TRY?

I found a suggestion online that this was some sort of a compilation error. Some support for that conclusion is provided by the behavior when the first call of the procedure after creation is with valid JSON:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestJSONParseProc
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);
        SELECT
            @v = v3
        FROM        TestJSONParse(@nv);
        SELECT v3 = @v;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            Result = N'I have caught an error.';
    END CATCH
END
GO

EXEC TestJSONParseProc
    @nv = N'{"prop": "Good JSON"}';

EXEC TestJSONParseProc
    @nv = N'zzzz';
GO
```

Results:

```
v3
Good JSON

v3
Bad JSON
```

Can anyone confirm that the reason this happens and why it can't be caught is because what's really happening is that SQL Server is evaluating the expression as part of the compilation process and therefore crashes before the error handling ever has a chance to work? (If so, is there any justification for this behavior?)

Or is there some other explanation?

For reference, @@VERSION returns:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    Feb 20 2021 17:51:58 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

---

Update 2021-04-27:

Things which don't fix the issue:

(1) Wrapping the JSON_VALUE in a CASE statment:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TestJSONParse
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        v3 = isNull(t2.v2,t1.v1)
    FROM        (
                    SELECT
                        v1 = 'Bad JSON'
                ) AS t1
    LEFT JOIN   (
                    SELECT
                        v2 = CASE WHEN ISJSON(@nv) <> 0 THEN JSON_VALUE(@nv,'$.prop') ELSE NULL END
                    WHERE ISJSON(@nv) <> 0
                ) AS t2
    ON          1 = 1
);
GO
```

(2a) "Touching" the parameter value to make it "different" - ISNULL

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestJSONParseProc
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);
        SET @nv = isNull(@nv,N'');
        SET @nv2 = @nv;
        SELECT
            @v = v3
        FROM        TestJSONParse(@nv);
        SELECT v3 = @v;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            Result = N'I have caught an error.';
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

(2b) "Touching" the parameter value to make it "different" - concatenate empty string

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestJSONParseProc
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);
        SET @nv = @nv + N'';
        SELECT
            @v = v3
        FROM        TestJSONParse(@nv);
        SELECT v3 = @v;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            Result = N'I have caught an error.';
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

(3) Wrapping entire function call in ISJSON check

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestJSONParseProc
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);
        IF ISJSON(@nv) <> 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @v = v3
            FROM        TestJSONParse(@nv);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Bad JSON',15,1);
        END
        SELECT v3 = @v;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            Result = N'I have caught an error.';
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Declaring a new variable in the proc and using that does, however, fix the issue:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestJSONParseProc
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);
        DECLARE @nv2 nvarchar(max);
        SET @nv2 = @nv;
        SELECT
            @v = v3
        FROM        TestJSONParse(@nv2);
        SELECT v3 = @v;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            Result = N'I have caught an error.';
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

That also bolsters the case that it's some sort of parameter sniffing compilation issue.

---

Update 2021-04-28:

As [Mikael Eriksson](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2103/mikael-eriksson) suggested in a comment, using OPTIMIZE FOR @nv = NULL works as well. As noted, this also bolsters the case for this being a compile-time issue.

If a set of valid objects which would run successfully won't compile because of how the optimizer evaluates them, I would argue that's a bug in the optimizer/compiler.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestJSONParseProc
(
    @nv nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);
        SELECT
            @v = v3
        FROM        TestJSONParse(@nv)
        OPTION      (OPTIMIZE FOR (@nv = NULL));
        SELECT v3 = @v;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            Result = N'I have caught an error.';
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: Instead of using a local variable as a workaround you could also do `option (optimize for (@nv = null))` to the same effect. It do suggest that your own conclusion is correct that the error happens before exectution.

Comment: I concur with you: it does appear to be a parameter sniffing bug. I suggest you file it on Azure Feedback

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`ISJSON()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to verify the column is valid JSON in the `SELECT` clause regardless of the `WHERE` clause. The reasoning for this is because contrary to popular belief, sometimes the SQL Engine generates an **execution plan** where it finds it more efficient to evaluate the `SELECT` clause before the `WHERE` clause is applied. That results in these *odd* cases where an exception is thrown unbeknownst to the average developer why.

So inside your `TestJSONParse()` function you'll need to change the line of code `v2 = JSON_VALUE(@nv,'$.prop')` to `v2 = CASE WHEN ISJSON(@nv) = 1 THEN JSON_VALUE(@nv,'$.prop') ELSE NULL`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, but see update where that didn't work.

Comment: @RileyMajor Are you 100% sure you accurately tested `v2 = CASE WHEN ISJSON(@nv) = 1 THEN JSON_VALUE(@nv,'$.prop') ELSE NULL`?...I've experienced this same issue (sans a JSON function but using other functions and operators) and the reasoning I mentioned was the exact issue occuring. Perhaps ensure you recompiled the `TestJSONParseProc` procedure **after** you updated the `TestJSONParse()` function? (It shouldn't matter, but for good measure.)

Comment: Yes, I did. in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2016 locally. Perhaps it's because the CASE function doesn't always save you from executing its innards inappropriately (https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression). Or perhaps because this is a compile-time issue so it's not actually executing and therefore doesn't respect the flow. (That would also explain why wrapping the whole function call in ISJSON doesn't help.)

Comment: @RileyMajor Hmm... Wrapping the whole function call with `ISJSON()` is outside the scope of the `SELECT` clause where your issue is stemming from, so I understand why that wouldn't fix things. Do you receive the error message you provided in your post at compile time or runtime? If runtime then I don't think this is a compile time issue. But I do see your link on `CASE` statements not always covering the issue I described unfortunately. I think in my past experiences with this issue I was able to resolve this with using functions like `TRY_CONVERT()` instead, but I don't think `JSON` is an...

Comment: ...applicable data type for `TRY_CONVERT()` unfortunately. I'd have to think a little bit for your scenario and research if there's an alternative function you can use.

Comment: Correct, it doesn't have a TRY_CONVERT as JSON (unlike XML) isn't really a data type in SQL Server. It's not happening at *save* time; it lets me save the objects. It's happening at time of execution. But SQL code is "compiled" at runtime, so ti's not easy to tell whether it's compile-time or run-time, technically. Suspicion is compile-time based on info in "update" section of question above. The wrapping of the function call *should* have fixed it because the function wouldn't even be executed, and the function is where the error "occurs".

Comment: @RileyMajors Wrapping of the function is irrelevant because similarly to how a `CASE` statement can be evaluated fully, so can the `SELECT` statement of your inner function even though it's not realistically suppose to execute. Again, with this issue, I've always fixed it by addressing right at the root cause which is the `SELECT` clause itself, as your error message points out. Unfortunately if you were able to do a `TRY_CONVERT()` on `JSON` as a data type, I think that would definitely solve your problem, but right it's not a data type like XML is.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in SQL Server's compilation/optimization system.

A feedback item has been submitted:

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/072ac3a7-5825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

> JSON Parsing Error during Compilation / Optimization
>
> Invalid JSON in a parameter can cause an error during the
> compilation/optimization phase, bypassing any TRY/CATCH logic. The
> only way around the issue is to use query hints like OPTIMIZE FOR, use
> an internal variable, or to run through valid JSON the first time the
> procedure is called.